# Need help aligning div menu inside of a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a social media menu for my about page. I just can't get it to align properly inside of of another div nor on it's own. It just sits kind of off center and I want it to float left with 100px margin or for it to be nested in the other div. On my page I have another div that's centered as a nav bar.

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
<div id="social" class="ul li">
<ul>
<li>
<div class="caption">Linkedin</div> 
<img src='linkedin.png'/>

</li>
<li>
<div class="caption">Twitter</div><img src='twitter.png'/>

</li>
<li>
<div class="caption">Github</div>
<img src='github.png'/>
</li>
<li>
<div class="caption">Facebook</div><img src='facebook.png'/>
</li>
<li>
<div class="caption">Instagram</div>
<img src='instagram.png'/>
</li>
<li>
<div class="caption">Hangouts</div>
<img src='hangouts.png'/>
</li>
<li>
<div class="caption">Yelp</div>
<img src='yelp.png'/>
</li>
<li>
<div class="caption">Pinterest</div>
<img src='pinterest.png'/>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.social ul li div {
display: none;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 45px;
```

**jQuery**

```
$('ul li').mouseenter(function () {
var image = $(this).find('img'),
    caption = $(this).find('div');

caption.width(image.width());
caption.height(image.height());
caption.fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function () {
var image = $(this).find('img'),
    caption = $(this).find('div');

caption.width(image.width());
caption.height(image.height());
caption.fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: could you please share a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with us, or if you can add an image specifying your actual need..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lwhateley/auehLa0h/

Comment: ok..and now what is that you actually need?

Comment: i need this to float left on my page or stay within a div. it keeps showing up in the middle but not centered either and it seems to not stick within the div's width.

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/auehLa0h/2/) what you need??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are asking. I believe you are trying to get your #social div to position itself 100px from the left if I am correct. If that is the case you can do so by adding this css

```
    #social{
        position:absolute;
        left:100px;
    }
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/auehLa0h/3/) running this code. If that does not answer your question I am sorry if I am confused on what you are asking. Could you you maybe re explain and simplify it for me and I will give it another shot.